# Failed to write session data

Tags: apache-2.2, php.ini

I have a VPS running on CentOS 5 with Plesk 9.
My website us running on FastCGI.

I'm having problems reading / writing sessions. On my servers `error_log` I get the following errors:

```
(...) Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0  

(...) open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_v8g5rt6p83b9one3mlg9sh9ts0, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm tempted to change

`session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"`
to
`session.save_path = "/tmp"`

The problem is that `/tmp` has chmod 777, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to go?

**Update**
The `session` dir has the following rights:  `-rwxrwx---` User `root` Group `apache`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you fix the permissions on `/var/lib/php/session`?  This directory simply needs to be writeable by the httpd user (which, depending on your os, may be something like `www-data` or `apache`; look for the `User` directive in your `httpd.conf`).

The commands will look something like:

```
chown apache /var/lib/php/session
chmod 700 /var/lib/php/session
```

This makes the directory writeable by the `apache` user, and generally inaccessible to everyone else.

Comment: I think my `session` dir already has 770 (`-rwxrwx---`). User is `root` and group is `apache`

Comment: httpd.conf says that user and group is `apache`.

Comment: Do you have your FastCGI environment configured to run your applications under a different user ID?  If you temporarily change the permissions to mode 777, then allow PHP to create a session file, you can then look at the ownership on that file to see for certain -- and then use that information to correctly set the permissions on the session directory.

Comment: +1 - this is the better option

Comment: Brilliant. Worked like a charm!  This will significantly reduce the error_log entries :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after I switched to running php using fcgi to solve permissions problems.  Prior to this change, php scripts ran as apache:apache which resulted in permissions errors (unless you `chmod 777`'d all directories which is very dangerous).  After switching to the fcgi method of running php, php scripts now run as user  group psacln, however the /var/lib/php/session directory was still owned by root:apache.  My solution was to `chown root:psacln /var/lib/php/session ; chmod 770 /var/lib/php/session`